# Amazon Aws Question: What is the unix command to run on an EC2 Instance, that'll tell you what region the server is in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-ec2

Is there a unix command to run on an amazon ec2 instance which will return back what region & availiabity zone the current instance is in?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a [tool](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1825?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1) to get instance metadata - Region, Availability zone, public hostname etc. 
Also there is a [HTTP API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html)  you can use to find out the same information.